# Block Access Application while using Java Application

Tags: java, ms-access, vba

I'm working on a drag-and-drop Java interface run from an Access form.

My problem is that if the user clicks on the background (the Access Application), it will provoke a bug of the Accesss Apllication, so I want to block Access when the Java application is running like Access blocks one form when a second is opened.

Here is the function I use to run my jar :

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Const INFINITE = &HFFFFFFFF
Private Const SYNCHRONIZE = &H100000
Private Const PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = &H400&

Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, lpExitCode As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hHandle As Long, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
    ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long

Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal IngMilliseconds As Long)

'Shell and wait.  Return exit code result, raise an exception on any error.
Public Function ShellSync(ByVal PathName As String, ByVal WindowStyle As VbAppWinStyle) As Long
Dim lngPid As Long
Dim lngHandle As Long
Dim lngExitCode As Long

lngPid = Shell(PathName, WindowStyle)
If lngPid <> 0 Then
    lngHandle = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE Or PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, 0, lngPid)
    If lngHandle <> 0 Then
        WaitForSingleObject lngHandle, INFINITE
        If GetExitCodeProcess(lngHandle, lngExitCode) <> 0 Then
            ShellSync = lngExitCode
            CloseHandle lngHandle
        Else
            CloseHandle lngHandle
            Err.Raise &H8004AA00, "ShellSync", "Failed to retrieve exit code, error " & CStr(Err.LastDllError)
        End If
    Else
        Err.Raise &H8004AA01, "ShellSync", "Failed to open child process"
    End If
Else
    Err.Raise &H8004AA02, "ShellSync", "Failed to Shell child process"
End If
End Function
```

Comment: *like Access blocks one form when a second is opened* - you mean using modal dialogs? Seems like going through a lot of trouble just to make a dialog modal and owned by the host app's mainwindow. So what's the question? "it will provoke a bug" is rather vague, is any specific error thrown?

Comment: yes i want to make the java window as modal window

Comment: here is a screenshot https://imgur.com/a/8b9ZW8O

Comment: and it provokes application not responding error when i click on the Access application area

Comment: If `WaitForSingleObject` will halt host application's execution until the time specified. if you would like to remain responsive, you must capture and process the messages like DoEvents would do in a loop. Search for `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`. Just out of curiocity, what's that JAR doing?

Comment: Ty for your helps, the JAR is an interface for drag and drop of Outlook attachments to Access and i'm still seeking the solution. WaitForSingleObject doesn't work for me because when the host application's is hidden its parent forms will be activated.

Comment: what i want it's to run my jar as modal to the entire Access application, i've tried Application.visible, Application.echo and so on but there isnt a method like Application.eventsEnabled one from Excel.

Comment: I don't know if we can make the jar modal to his caller application or a process modal to another one.

Comment: Maybe not what you are looking for but have a look in [Drag and drop for vba](https://github.com/krishKM/VBA_TOOLS/blob/master/README.md#drag-and-drop-openfiledialog)